# How to store image name as File Content in(ir.attachment) in odoo?

Tags: image, odoo, odoo-11

When I created a product in 'product.template' that time I give the image for the particular record. So the record creates successfully but when I check the attachment of that record using Postgres.

```
select * from ir_attachment where res_id=107 and res_model='product.template'
```

After I go to attachment record and check the File Content name is blank. So When I was the download the image name is given False.

[image: 1]

So how to resolve this issue and it is odoo default flow.

Answer (score 1):

In Odoo 11 this is a problem. So that you have to add an extra field for the name itself. For example;

in `python` class

```
attachment = fields.Binary(string="Attachment", track_visibility="onchange")
fname = fields.Char(string="File Name", track_visibility="onchange")
```

in `XML`:

```
<group>
    <field name="attachment" filename="fname" widget="download_link" string="Attachment"/>
    <field name="fname" invisible="1"/>
</group>
```

Try this, this will work. Don't forget to upvote and put tick mark too. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my question related to product image so need  product image related solution overcome

Answer (score 1):

In Odoo 12

Python:

```
  file_name = fields.Char("File Name")
  attachment = fields.Binary("Image")
```

XML

```
 <field name="file_name" invisible="1"/>
 <field name="attachment" filename="file_name" widget="FieldBinary"/>
```